# Least prime quadratic residue

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-residues

I'm not sure I understand what the least prime quadratic residue $l(p)$ of a prime number $p$ is.

For example, $l(2)$ and $l(3)$ do not exist, right? Because the quadratic residue are $0$ and $0,1$ respectively, none of them prime numbers.

But $l(11)=3$, because $5^2\equiv 3 \mod 11$, and $2$ is a non-residue.

> Is this correct, or am I misunderstanding que concept?

Comment: it seems $l(3) = 7$, because the [definition of $l(q)$](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X86900260) is $\min \{p \in \mathcal{P} \ \mid \ \left(\frac{p}{q} \right) = 1\}$